# Android navigation drawer: center menu vertically in NavigationView

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer

I am using NavigationView from the `android.support.design` library.
I want to make it's menu be vertically centered.

So, instead of the default alignement...

[image]

... I want it to look something like this:

[image]

From what I could see there are no layout attributes in `NavigationView`that would help me achieve this. I tried with `android:foregroundGravity="center_vertical"` but had no luck.

Does anybody know of a way to solve this without having to change `NvigationView` for a different layout?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't look like this is possible without creating a custom NavigationView.

However, because NavigationView is a SubClass of FrameLayout; you can add your own Views into it.

You could therefore not set menu items but add your own ListView (setting `android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"`).

Obviously you would then need to implement a ListAdapter and cannot use OnNavigationItemSelectedListener which is not ideal.

Comment: Yeah, that was my thinking as well. I would have liked to find a solution that still uses the NavigationView so I wouldn't have to change a lot of code.

Comment: I ended up using a solution based on your answer, thanks. I'll post it when I have some spare time.

Comment: Great - glad you got your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Too late, but this is for new people.
You can create a `RelativeLayout` in the `NavigationActivity` which will contain an `android:layout_gravity="start"` so that it remains positioned to the left of the window, `android:gravity="center_vertical"` so that the " Navigation View" is vertically centered on the "RelativeLayout" and `app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_home"` to change the menu container when doing the java side `onClickListener`.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_home"
    layout="@layout/app_bar_home"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<RelativeLayout
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_home"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/bg_dark"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="start">

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/bg_dark"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/white"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_home_drawer" />
</RelativeLayout>
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

[You can watch the result of this here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpmnM.png)

Answer (score 0):

When I add `app:itemHorizontalPadding="80dp"` to my `activity_main.xml` file
It worked and my navigation menu items are aligned to the center
So I think it's the easiest solution to this problem

**MY CODE:**
[image: screenshot of my code]

Comment: Please add your code in form of text, not image.